# Golang Regex : how can I filter loss(...) : {value} stiring

Tags: regex, go

```
"([\\w|-]+)\\s*:\\s*((-?\\d+)(\\.\\d+)?)"
```

I heard that this matches with `{}`: {} format in Golang

I want to catch `loss(...) : {}` string

for example:

`Total: 0:06:53 | ETA: 0:08:26 | loss: 1.1260 | loss_2d: 0.1125 | loss_3d_rel: 0.3900 | loss_3d_abs: 0.1651 | loss_smpl: 0.3662`

I want:

```
loss: 1.1260
loss_2d: 0.1125
loss_3d_rel: 0.3900
loss_3d_abs: 0.1651
loss_smpl: 0.3662
```

I'm not familiar with Regex...
how can I filter above?
Thanks..

Comment: Edit the question to show the expected output for the given inputs.  Remove the python tag or explain how the question is related to Python.

Comment: If you want loss and the values `\b(loss\w*)\s*:\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b` https://regex101.com/r/3k2suV/1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find all values containing `loss` you might be looking for something like this.

```
package main


import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    input := `Total: 0:06:53 | ETA: 0:08:26 | loss: 1.1260 | loss_2d: 0.1125 | loss_3d_rel: 0.3900 | loss_3d_abs: 0.1651 | loss_smpl: 0.3662`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`loss(\w*):\s(\d.\d*)`)
    matches := re.FindAllString(input,-1)
    
    for _,v := range matches {
      fmt.Println(v)
    }

}
```